# Reverse of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I have a question about a statistical concept and would like to gather your thoughts on it. As we know, the Central Limit Theorem states that under certain conditions, the sum or average of **independent** and **identically distributed** random variables tends to a normal distribution as the sample size increases. However, I am pondering the reverse of this theorem:

If the sum of random variables $x_1, x_2 ... x_n$ exhibits a normal distribution, can we infer that these variables are independent? In other words, is a sum that conforms to a normal distribution sufficient to indicate the independence of the variables?

Do we have any idea or reference?

Comment: Nope. There are central limit theorems for sums of dependent variables, such as the Hypergeometric Distribution. There are also trivial counterexamples like $x_1 = Z$, $x_2 = x_3 = \dots = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. It is not possible to grant that if $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ has normal distribution, then $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are independents.

In fact, if you check the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) of the CLT, you will find that it exist several versions of the CLT and the "CLT under weak dependence" does not require the independence of the samples.